# How much should he drop the price of beer to match Tesco

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my local cornershop, they are selling 12 cans of Fosters (500ml cans) for £10.99. I told the owner that in Tesco, they are selling 24 cans of Fosters (440ml) for £15. So me and him were thinking how much he would need to reduce his prices by so they are similar, or he is undercutting Tesco.

My method was this:

$$\frac{10.99}{12} \approx £0.91\text{} \, \, \text{  a can},$$

which works out to be

$$\frac{0.91}{500} \approx £0.00183\text{} \, \, \text{per ml}.$$

for the corner shop.

Tesco, therefore sells it at

$$\frac{15}{24} \approx £0.63\text{} \, \, \text{a can},$$

which ends up being $£0.0014$ per ml.

Is this correct so far?

From here, how do we then deduce how much we have to drop the price by?

Comment: You can take $p_c\over p_T$ as the ratio of "price per can at corner versus price per can at Tesco", then apply the inverse of that ratio to the price per set of cans at the corner store...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct so far.

Now just multiply $$\dfrac{£0.0014}{\text{ ml. }} \times \dfrac {500 \text{ ml }}{1\text{ can}} \times 12 \text{ cans}$$

And the result will give you the closely approximated price at which the cost of $12$ cans of Fosters (500 ml per can) will equal the per ml cost of Fosters at the competitor (24 cans at 440 ml/can).  Then subtract the above answer from $£10.99$ to obtain the amount to charge to *match* the competitor, and subtract a wee bit more to be at a price less than the competitor.